Why is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma_a(pn)}{n^s}=(1+p^a-p^{a-s}) \zeta(s) \zeta(s-a)$ only when $p$ is a prime number?
I tried to find the summation for $a,b\in N$ and $s>a+1$
$$ \Omega_a(b,s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma_a(bn)}{n^s}$$
where $\sigma_a(n)$ is sum of positive divisors function which defined by
$$ \sigma_a(n)=\sum_{d|n} d^a$$
its easy to show that
$$\Omega_a(b,s)=b^{s-1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^a \sum_{p=1}^b
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{2nkp\pi i}{b}}}{(nk)^s}$$
then
$$=b^{s-1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{s-a}} \sum_{p=1}^b\text{Li}_s \left( e^{\frac{2kp\pi i}{b}} \right)$$
or
$$=b^{s-1} \sum_{p=1}^{b} \sum_{j=0}^{b-1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(bk-j)^{s-a}} \, \text{Li}_s \left( e^{\frac{2(bk-j)p\pi i}{b}} \right)$$
finally
$$=b^{a-1} \sum_{p=1}^{b} \sum_{j=0}^{b-1} \text{Li}_s \left( e^{-\frac{2pj\pi i}{b}} \right) \zeta(s-a, \frac{b-j}{b})$$
and by Mathematica I got some initial formulas then I believe this formula is true for primes $p>2$
$$\Omega_a(p,s)=\left( (p-1) \times p^{a-1} + p^{s-1} + \left( p^{a-1} - p^{s-1} \right) \frac{-1}{\zeta(s)} \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \text{Li}_s \left( e^{-\frac{(p-1)j\pi i}{p}} \right) \right) \zeta(s) \zeta(s-a)$$
and for that series lets denote it by $f_n(s)$ where
$$ f_n(s)=\frac{-1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \text{Li}_s \left( e^{-\frac{(n-1)k}{n} \pi i}\right)$$
also by Mathematica I found that
$$f_3(s)=1-3^{1-s}$$
and
$$f_5(s)=1-5^{1-s} \\ f_7(s)=1-7^{1-s} \\ f_{11}(s)=1-11^{1-s} $$
this initial forms is not difficult to show.
MY QUESTIONS

is it true that
$$p^{a-1} \sum_{p=1}^{p} \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} \text{Li}_s \left( e^{-\frac{2pj\pi i}{p}} \right) \zeta(s-a, \frac{p-j}{p})=\left( (p-1) \times p^{a-1} + p^{s-1} + \left( p^{a-1} - p^{s-1} \right) \frac{-1}{\zeta(s)} \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \text{Li}_s \left( e^{-\frac{(p-1)j\pi i}{p}} \right) \right) \zeta(s) \zeta(s-a)$$
for all primes $p>2$? and what if $p$ is not prime ?

Is that relation true for primes $p>2$


$$ \frac{-1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \text{Li}_s \left( e^{-\frac{(p-1)k}{p} \pi i}\right)=1-p^{1-s}$$
and if it is true, does that mean
$$ \prod_{p : \text{prime}>2} \frac{-1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \text{Li}_s \left( e^{-\frac{(p-1)k}{p} \pi i}\right)=\frac{1}{(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s-1)} $$

Is that formula true for primes $p$  (its true also for $p=1$)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sigma_a(pn)}{n^s}=(1+p^a-p^{a-s}) \zeta(s) \zeta(s-a)$$


The notation $\Omega_a(bn)$ is confusing, especially when the summation defining it uses index parameter $n$ already.

Better to edit the definition of $\sigma_a(bn)$ into the body of the question, than to make every user chase it offsite.

@MarkSchultz-Wu Yes, I’ve fixed it. Thank you for your comment, and I apologize for the oversight

@GerryMyerson Okay, I've implement your suggestions. Thank you!

Please restrict to one question per post (which is standard policy on this site). I will answer your third question (which includes the question in the title).
We start from the standard Hecke multiplicativity relations
$$\sigma_a(m)\sigma_a(n)=\sum_{d\mid(m,n)}d^a\sigma_a\left(\frac{mn}{d^2}\right),\qquad
\sigma_a(mn)=\sum_{d\mid(m,n)}\mu(d)d^a\sigma_a\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)\sigma_a\left(\frac{n}{d}\right).$$
In fact these are equivalent by Möbius inversion, and either of them can be checked easily by restricting $m$ and $n$ to be the powers of the same prime (with nonnegative exponents). At any rate, the second relation gives that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_a(bn)}{n^s}
&=\sum_{d\mid b}\mu(d)d^a\sigma_a\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)\sum_{d\mid n}\sigma_a\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\frac{1}{n^s}\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{d\mid b}\mu(d)d^{a-s}\sigma_a\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_a(m)}{m^s}\\[6pt]
&=\zeta(s)\zeta(s-a)\sum_{d\mid b}\mu(d)d^{a-s}\sigma_a\left(\frac{b}{d}\right).
\end{align*}
The last sum is a multiplicative function of $b$ since it is the Möbius convolution of two multiplicative functions. If $b=p^k$ is a prime power $(k\geq 1)$, then it equals
$$\sigma_a(p^k)-p^{a-s}\sigma_a(p^{k-1}).$$
In particular, for $k=1$ (i.e. when $b=p$ is a prime), this equals $1+p^a-p^{a-s}$.
To sum up, the general formula is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_a(bn)}{n^s}=\zeta(s)\zeta(s-a)\prod_{p^k\parallel b}\left(\sigma_a(p^k)-p^{a-s}\sigma_a(p^{k-1})\right),$$
where the product is over the factors in the prime power factorization of $b$.

Sure I will keep that in mind for my future questions. Thanks for your solution , you have solved the main question.
